# Output for simple program using pthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

```
void cleanupHandler(void *arg) { 
    printf("In the cleanup handler\n");
}
void *Thread(void *string) { 
    int i;
    int o_state;
    int o_type;
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanupHandler, NULL);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &o_state);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &o_type);
    puts("1 Hello World");
    pthread_setcancelstate(o_state, &o_state);
    puts("2 Hello World");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main() { 
    pthread_t th;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&th, NULL, Thread, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(th);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I was wondering what the output of this code would be and in what order they would happen.  Yes, this is a practice test question for an exam I have in 6 hours.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  There are no office hours today as all of the TA's for my college are busy with their own finals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the man pages you need to understand the problem they will be putting on the exam (which most certainly won't be the exact problem above.)  So you need to understand what each of those functions does.

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html,
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html
- `cleanup_push` pushs a handler on a stack of functions that will be called if the calling thread is cancelled or exits.
- `setcancelstate` temporarily locks out cancels (so that you can call `setcanceltype` atomically without weirdness happening.)
- `setcanceltype` allows/disallows asynchronous cancellation notification.
- `cancel` actually attempts to cancel the other thread.
- `exit` exits from the calling thread.
- You also need to understand whether `pthread_setcancelstate` is a cancellation point.  You will find that information either on the above man pages or on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html.

In this question (and presumably the similar one that will be on your exam), you need to enumerate all possible interleavings of calls to these functions between the two threads.

Answer (score -2):

```
1 Hello World
2 Hello World
```

Why not just compile it and run it?  This version compiles and runs.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void cleanupHandler(void *arg) {
    printf("In the cleanup handler\n");
}
void* Thread(void *string) {
    int i;
    int o_state;
    int o_type;
    sleep(1);
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanupHandler, NULL);

    sleep(1);//Note that when you uncomment lines, you should uncomment them in order.
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &o_state);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &o_type);
    puts("1 Hello World");
    sleep(1);
    pthread_setcancelstate(o_state, &o_state);
    sleep(1);
    puts("2 Hello World");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t th;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&th, NULL, Thread, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(th);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: "Why not just compile it and run it?" Because that won't help prepare for an exam where, presumably, you're expected to understand why you get that output.

Comment: There [are/are not?] other possible outputs.  That's why it's a good practice exam question.  You need to understand which of these functions can be interleaved and which not.

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes it's faster to learn by running something and compiling it, then trying to force these interleaving circumstances to occur, because of the simplicity of this example, realistically this is a deterministic example, without some dabbling.  I personally find dabbling with compiled code more useful than man pages, which is why I threw in the code that would actually compile and run for him.

Comment: Thank you mike.  Had I the ability in the current environment I am in to run I would have.  Also, I am pretty new to this stuff so I wanted to also know WHY it would give me the certain outputs.

Comment: And also thank you for the links to the man pages.. This has been very very helpful.  Thank you both!!!

Comment: If you would like to understand why things are happening, try commenting/uncommenting the various sleep lines.  This along with man references, should help you understand what's going on.  Predicting how uncommenting a certain sleep line will effect output will be good exam practice.